# JsonSerializationException from empty dictionary json

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to desterilize a json string that is set as `"{}"` as an empty dictionary and I am seeing this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

```
        public Dictionary<string, string> FileMetadataItems { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        private IQueryable<FileSystemItemMetadataDTO> GetFileSystemMetadataQueryable()
        {
            var files = BIContext.FileSystemItems
                        .Select(x => new FileSystemItemMetadataDTO()
                        {
                            FileId = x.FileId,
                            FileName = x.FileName,
                            FileType = x.FileType,
                            IsFolder = x.IsFolder,
                            LastWriteTime = x.LastWriteTime,
                            ParentId = x.ParentId,
                            FileLength = 0,
                            FileSystemItemDataId = x.FileSystemItemDataId,
                            FileSize = x.FileSize,
                            FileMetadata = x.FileMetadata,
                            ModuleId = x.ModuleId,
                            FileMetadataItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(x.FileMetadata),
                        });

            return files;
        }
```

Any ideas as to why the error occurring?

I tried setting a empty dictionary as the below but that errored as well.

```
{"name":"value"})
```

I also tried this:

```
        private IQueryable<FileSystemItemMetadataDTO> GetFileSystemMetadataQueryable()
        {
            var files = BIContext.FileSystemItems
                        .Select(x => new FileSystemItemMetadataDTO()
                        {
                            FileId = x.FileId,
                            FileName = x.FileName,
                            FileType = x.FileType,
                            IsFolder = x.IsFolder,
                            LastWriteTime = x.LastWriteTime,
                            ParentId = x.ParentId,
                            FileLength = 0,
                            FileSystemItemDataId = x.FileSystemItemDataId,
                            FileSize = x.FileSize,
                            FileMetadata = x.FileMetadata,
                            ModuleId = x.ModuleId,
                            FileMetadataItems = x.FileMetadata == "{}" ? new Dictionary<string, string>() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(x.FileMetadata),
                        });

            return files;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the empty dictionary is `{}` and not `[]` -- i.e. an empty array rather than an empty dictionary?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("{}");` works perfectly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/2twQAe.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Your current code will not even compile, lacking definitions for `FileSystemItemMetadataDTO` and `BIContext.FileSystemItems`.  You also don't include your JSON as **text**, just as a partial screen shot which is discouraged as per [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: @dbc: Could it be because I have it within the IQueryable()?

Comment: Maybe.  You have only [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question [tag:json.net] so we cannot know what framework you are using, what type `FileMetadata` is, or how to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your problem.  Honestly if you are querying an `IQueryable` representing some database query I am surprised the framework could even translate the expression `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(x.FileMetadata)` into a SQL query.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I moved the code outside of the IQueryable call and it works now. So I think that is the issue -> I was trying to deserialize it within the IQueryable call and the framework would just not translate it.

Comment: Glad that worked.  Are you going to make a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then?

Comment: @dbc: done! Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was due to doing the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(x.FileMetadata)` with the `IQueryable<FileSystemItemMetadataDTO> GetFileSystemMetadataQueryable()` method. Once I moved up to my service layer, it worked fine!